# How do you display a Neo4j graph in Jupyter lab or notebook?

Tags: neo4j, jupyter-notebook

Someone pointed me to this link:
http://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-jupyter/hello-world.html

It looks like it used to work before, but something got updated in py2neo or neo4j...

The repo is at:
https://github.com/nicolewhite/neo4j-jupyter

Does anyone have this working?

---

I've encountered 2 problems:

- The methods called are removed from the API (I've tried installing py2neo 3 (an older release) - but it would mess up something in jupyter.
- I've tried changing the script itself to use hard coded strings, but the jupyter lab notebook refuses to serve up the vis.css and .js resources (returning 403 forbidden). Maybe I didn't put those files in the right folder?

In the meantime, I guess I'll have to make do pasting a screenshot from the neo4j web interface into the notebook.

Will keep you posted if I make any progress on this.

Comment: To help try and debug this, there is a git template repo at https://github.com/psychemedia/binder-neo4j that lets you launch a MyBinder container running neo4j and Jupyter notebooks. On my to do list is adding in some graph visualisation tools.

Comment: THis cypher kernel — https://github.com/HelgeCPH/cypher_kernel — displays network diagrams from query results; this Binderised repo — https://github.com/psychemedia/binder-neo4j — bundles the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not suitable for you, but i hope my Hack will barely measure up to your problem.

1. stop Neo4j.
2. Download

   - 7zip
   - Javinder
   - jbe (Java Bytecode Editor)
3. Search for two entries using Javinder.

   - Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
   - X-Frame-Options: DENY
4. Open .jar with 7zip, extract and delete the corresponding file.
5. Open the extracted file with jbe and delete the corresponding entry (please note that the operation will be reflected immediately).
6. Write the modified file to .jar using 7zip.
7. start Neo4j
8. Open jupyter notebook with chrome.
9. Open Neo4j with iframe tag.
10. Do your work.
11. right click and print.

smpl file.
https://gist.github.com/nibuiro/bb7d14a6e6b87133ed74e04b4fd1403a